# Sticky Notes in Ubuntu as of windows

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, stickynotes

Hi I need to know about a sticky notes application in ubuntu similar to that of windows which pops up every time I boot my system as if a start up application.

Comment: the problem is they doesn't show up when I reboot my system

Comment: See the last line of accepted answer. "[See here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-to-start-applications-at-startup-automatically-in-unity) to run indicator-stickynotes on startup."